# Can i use symfony 2 with php without ICU

Tags: php, symfony

I have this recommendation for symfony

> Upgrade your intl extension with a newer ICU version (4+).

I want to know that if i don't do that will my apllication run or i have to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If can be problematic when using internationalisation stuff. But should work without too much problem for basic usage.

Comment: Thanks buddy i already spent two days searching for that om centos server. As i am only learning symfony so i think i can move with coding